# ClassFormatError on final class java8

Tags: java, class, java-8

I am getting an exception of `ClassFormatError` on a class:

```
import org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation;

import com.common.client.model.Error;

public final class ErrorHelper {

    /**
     * Private constructor as this is a utility class.
     */
    private ErrorHelper() {
        // do nothing.
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Error.
     * 
     * @param code
     *            The error code.
     * @param message
     *            The error message.
     * @return The new error.
     */
    public static Error createError(int code, String message) {
        Error error = new Error();
        error.setCode(String.valueOf(code));
        error.setMessage(message);
        return error;
    }

    /**
     * This method creates a JaxbRepresentation of the Error object.
     * 
     * @param code
     *            The error code.
     * @param message
     *            The error message.
     * @return The JaxbRepresentation of the error.
     * @deprecated call getErrorRepresentation from BaseResource
     */
    public static JaxbRepresentation<Error> getJaxbErrorRepresentation(
            int code, String message) {
        Error error = ErrorHelper.createError(code, message);
        JaxbRepresentation<Error> representation = new JaxbRepresentation<Error>(
                error);
        representation.setContextPath(Constants.JAXB_MODEL_PACKAGE);
        return representation;
    }

}
```

any idea?

Comment: Clean project and recompile. Seems your .class is corrupted

Comment: I checked the .class and nothing, looks ok, I can post it.

Comment: It is the same, I can't upload it because it is too long

Comment: Class files are not text files, so the problem is not length (it shouldn’t be bigger than ~200 bytes). You may post a hex dump of the file. But there’s a big likelihood that the problem is caused by a bytecode transformation tool that operates on-the-fly at runtime…

Comment: Are you saving your source code in a file named `ErrorHelper.class`? Don't do that. You need to save it as `ErrorHelper.java` and then use the Java compiler to produce `ErrorHelper.class`.

Comment: @Jesper: good point. Couldn’t think into *that* direction…

Comment: Of course my code is in .java file.  I mentioned the .class file because I was reading about it and people mentioned something with corrupted files